# PHP Fopen has old version of txt file, is it caching?

Tags: php, parsing, caching, fopen, txt

I use the parser below to grab data from a production data monitor (that stores it's data in text files for each job) and output to another php program to display data in a grid, its called about every 5 seconds on display refresh.

The data needs to be up to date, otherwise technicians are getting garbage data. Every few days, one of the jobs will get stuck and stop updating for several hours, even when the text file is updated every few seconds. Usually the only fix is to reboot the webserver entirely.

The webserver(Windows server 2019 running IIS10 and PHPv7.2) and production monitor(Windows 10 pro) are on the same domain with the production monitor's data folder shared to the webserver user.

Could the txt files be cached somehow? When the data gets stuck, the txt file is hours ahead of what the program is outputting, so it must not be reading from the data folder.

```
<?php
    function getData(){
        $scan = scan([Network Share Address For Data File]);
        $data = array();
          foreach ($scan as $x){  //loops through each snapshot file's path
            $parse = parse($x);
            $data[$parse['Machine']] = $parse;
          }
        return $data;
    }

    function parse($snapshot){   //Will read given text file from path and return array of data
        $file = fopen($snapshot, "r") or die("Unable to open!"); //open file in read mode
        $data = array();
        while(($line = fgets($file))!== false){
            if(strchr($line,"[")){  //If line starts with [ then it contains the job name
                $line = str_replace(array('[',']',"\n"),'',$line);
                $data += ['Job'=>$line];
            }elseif(strchr($line,"machine = ")){
                $line = (int)str_replace(array("machine = Machine ","\n"),"",$line);
                $data += ['Machine'=>$line];
            }elseif(strchr($line,"status = ")){
                $line = trim(str_replace(array("status = ","\n"),"",$line));
                $data += ['Status'=>$line];
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        return $data;
    }
    
    function scan($scanPath){ //Searches host folder for snapshot files and adds thier path to the return array
        $parseList = array();
        foreach (ScanDir($scanPath) as $jobDir){
            if (is_Dir($scanPath ."\\". $jobDir) && in_array("Snapshot.txt", scandir($scanPath ."\\". $jobDir))){
                array_push($parseList,$scanPath."\\".$jobDir."\\"."Snapshot.txt");
            }
        }
        return $parseList;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I see 3 functions, but no output? It is unclear to me how this works.

Comment: My apologies, the display program calls getdata() every refresh, which returns an array.

Comment: Have you tried using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: Ill give clearstatcache a try, that looks to be promising

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a caching mechanism in fopen - but I know from own experience, that windows can be very tricky on opening files simultaneasly, maybe the writing process blocks the reading.
You could work around the problem by flagging the written file as closed (by some timestamp maybe).

Comment: Unfortunately, windows is my only option for this. Its not necessarily a problem reading the file entirely, its that the data from a few individual txt files put into the getData() array is outdated and exists nowhere, sometimes 4-5 hours outdated information.

Comment: You could put a timestamp in the data array to see at what time the data was read and log the "Unable to open!" message with timestamp. This could help to track down the error.